# Managing an event loop in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm writing a class in a library that has an event processing loop:

```
class EventSystem(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self_process_loop)
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def _process_loop(self):
        while True:
            event = self.queue.get()
            self._handle_event(event)

    def _handle_event(self, event):
        ...
```

I've set the thread to be a `daemon` thread so it exits with the main program, but this means it could be killed mid-processing. I really want to wait for the current processing iteration to complete before it is killed.

Normally in these situations there's a flag being checked in the while loop and some method - `stop()`, say - that sets it `False`. I'd rather avoid this requirement if at all possible.

Is the following considered bad?

```
    def _process_loop(self):
        while True:
            event = self.queue.get()
            self.thread.daemon = False
            self._handle_event(event)
            self.thread.daemon = True
```

**Edit**: Yes it's bad: `RuntimeError: cannot set daemon status of active thread`

What would be the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: What's so bad about a flag to exit the while loop?  That's what I would use.

Comment: If there is another way I'd rather avoid this. It puts responsibility on the client to stop the background process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going on from umläute's answer (the idea of the child receiving info from the parent thread), I realised I can monitor the parent thread's state.

Making the thread non-daemon removes the issue of it exiting mid-processing. Then checking the parent thread to see if it's still running I can exit cleanly:

```
class EventSystem(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
    self.parent_thread = threading.current_thread()          # <-- Added
    self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self_process_loop)
    self.thread.start()

def _process_loop(self):
    while self.parent_thread.is_alive():                    # <-- Changed
        try:
            event = self.queue.get(timeout=1)               # <-- Timeout added
        except Queue.Empty:
            continue
        else:
            self._handle_event(event)

def _handle_event(self, event):
    ...
```

This introduces polling but is a viable solution that doesn't require the client to join with, or stop, the background thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct that you should (see the note in [this documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects)) use a flag, however you **cannot** use the internal `daemon` property as the flag, as it will return an error.

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) in Python:

> > daemon
> >     A boolean value indicating whether this thread is a daemon thread (True) or not (False). This must be set before start() is called, otherwise RuntimeError is raised. Its initial value is inherited from the creating thread; the main thread is not a daemon thread and therefore all threads created in the main thread default to daemon = False.

So you should create another variable to function as the flag.

Answer (score 1):

- use a condition variable that controls the life-cycle
- catch the signal that "kills" your daemon
- whenever the signal occurs, set the terminating condition, so the daemon quits once it has processed all events

Comment: Is there a signal sent to the child thread? I thought signals were process-level. If there is one and it can be handled, this would be a good solution. Do you have any details?